# When choosing between a Listview.builder and SingleChildScrollView, how do we assess the performance gain in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a `listview.builder` of various sized elements, but about 20 total elements.  These elements contain a variety of widgets such as images, video, text, etc..

I need to scroll to a certain index, which seems impossible with the current implementation of `listview.builder`, so I'm considering changing the entire structure to a `SingleChildScrollView` with the entire page laid out all at once.

From a performance POV, the wisdom seems to be for small lists a `SingleChildScrollView` is just fine but for large lists the `listview.builder` is superior as it will only build a finite number of elements that are currently being shown to the user.  Makes sense.

##### But...  how do we gauge what is considered a small number of elements vs a large list?

How do we know that we've crossed the performance threshold of choosing one structure over another?

For now I'm just loading the lists onto a device and seeing how laggy it feels, but is there a more objective way of making this determination?

With my specific case use of about 20 rows containing a mixture of images, text and videos, am I way in the clear for using the SingleChildScrollView?

Comment: Why not check performance by running in the profile mode?

Comment: I don't think this is the right way of phrasing your question. `SingleChildScrollView` doesn't necessarily have anything to do with lists. It's just for making a Widget scrollable, for instance if I have a really tall `Container` I might wrap it in a `SingleChildScrollView`. So, in order to use one with a list, you must build your list/`Column` beforehand. That means the question you're really asking is "Can I write a function that constructs a list of widgets more quickly than `ListView.builder` does?" - unless by "performance" you just mean FPS when scrolling.